# c# - Google Calendar API GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker Hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to run Google Calendar API from an ASP.NET MVC C# web application. When I debug in this mode the code hangs on the line with `credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` I'm assuming it is trying to do work and times out, but I don't receive any feedback from the browser or Visual Studio.

```
public void AddEventToCalendar(ConcertModel concert)
{
    var scope = new[] {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar};

    UserCredential credential;

    var fileName = @"G:\\Source\\Hudl\\Hudl\\Hudl\\Content\\client_secrets.json";
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {

        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            scope, "user", CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore("Calendar.Vb.Sample")).Result;
    }

    var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
    initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
    initializer.ApplicationName = "VB.NET Calendar Sample";
    _service = new CalendarService(initializer);

    IList<CalendarListEntry> list = _service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;

    DisplayList(list);
    foreach (var calendar in list)
    {
        DisplayFirstCalendarEvents(calendar);
    }
}
```

I am running in .NET 4.0 with the beta version of Microsoft.Bcl.Async v1.0.166

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Nope, switched over to the Javascript API.